# Regexp dart for arabic characters in dart

Tags: regex, string, dart, unicode, hashtag

How are you?

I am a beginner in dart and flutter and I am also a new programmer and It's the first time I ask a question on StackOverflow.

I am training now on regular expressions and I am trying to create a one to match all characters with hashtag sign like:

- `#I_am_here`
- `#Stop`

anyway, everything is going okay but actually, when I try to replace the string which is in English with Arabic I get stuck.

---

```dart
void main() {
  String text = "#اسمي_هنا";
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\B#\w\w+" , unicode: true , multiLine: true);
  exp.allMatches(text).forEach((match) {
    print(match.group(0));

    if (match.group(0) == null) {
      print(null);
    }
  });

}
```

it doesn't even prints null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tries to actually do what I want I found that the best solution is:

```dart
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"([#][^\s#]*)");
  String str = "#الالاا_سيسيسشي_لأيبيبالابل";
  exp.allMatches(str).forEach((m) {
    print(
      m.group(0),
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\w` character is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. In your case, you are using an Arabic Alphabet, so the expression will not match, since `A-Z` belongs to a Latin Alphabet.

One way to go around it is to use `\p{L}`, this will basically match *any letter*, regardless of language. For more information on the topic, you can looking into regular expressions with an interest in unicode matches.

EDIT:
As per your comment, the issue with this section of the expression: `#\p{L}+[_]+\p{L}+`, the engine is **expecting** a hash, letters (one or more), followed by an underscore (one or more) followed by letters (one or more).

In your other example, wherein we can have the following form of string: `#foo` and `#foo_bar`, we need to ammend the expression such that the `_bar` section is optional. To do this, we alter the expression as follows:  `#\p{L}+([_]+\p{L}+)?`. In this case, the engine is now expecting either `#foo` or `#foo_bar`. If you need to match anything of the form: `#foo_bar_hello`, you can also use `#\p{L}+([_]+\p{L}+)+`.

Comment: I am using ```RegExp(r"\B#\p{L}\p{L}+" , unicode: true , multiLine: true)``` and when I use a string like this : '#اسمي_هنا' it prints #اسمي (the first word only) what is the problem

Comment: Can you try `RegExp(r"\B#\p{L}+[_]+\p{L}+` @notworking? AFAIK `_` is not matched with `\p{L}`. You can put any other characters separating the words you are parsing in the square brackets.

Comment: I've noticed that it doesn't work when I use hashtag of one word such as: ``` #Here  ``` what should I do ? @nipinti

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField
(
        inputFormatters: 
        [ WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-z\u0621-\u064a-\ ]",unicode: true)), ],
)
```